# How to click after my function read a barcode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to click in a search button after my app reads a barcode, but so far it's without success.

My search button is `$scope.buscar`

How do I do this after `$('#txtCode').val(imageData.text);` ?

**BarCode Ctrl**

```
.controller("BarCode", function( $scope, $cordovaBarcodeScanner){
   $scope.scanBarcode = function(){    
         $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(imageData){
           $('#txtCode').val(imageData.text);

            }, function(error){
              console.log('Deu Merda'+error);
          });
    }
})
```

**People & Corpo Ctrl**

```
.controller('PeopleCtrl',function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.people = [];

    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
        var httpRequest = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'json/clientes.json',
        }).success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.people = data;
        });

     });

})

.controller('CtrlCorpo',function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.people = [];

    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
        var httpRequest = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'json/clientes.json',
        }).success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.people = data;
        });

     });
```

**Search Button**

```
        $scope.buscar = function (){
            angular.forEach($scope.people, function(c, i) {
                var item = "<td><a href=cardapio.html?"+c.id+">"+ c.id + "</a></td>" + "<td>"+ c.name +"</td>"
                if(c.id == $('#txtCode').val()){
                    $('#tabelaPessoa').html(''),
                    $('#tabelaPessoa').append(item);
                }
            }
        );

        }
});
```

I have to search in `JSON` all clients and Start my APP showing.

When I click in my BarCodeScanner button, I'll read the ID and automatically I've to search and if exists. Automatically enter in the second page 'cardapio.html?clientid'. For now I'm trying to search after reading the barcode.

Comment: I tried : angular.element('#btBusca').triggerHandler('click'); But doesn't worked too...

Comment: I tried : $scope.buscar(); Doesn't worked...

Comment: I tried $('#btBusca').click(); Doesn't Worked...

Comment: Is `$scope.buscar` under the `barcode` ctrl? If not then under what controller is `$scope.buscar`.

Comment: My button is under the control of CtrlCorpo which in turn is under the control Barcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are attempting to access a scope outside your controller.

> My button is under the control of `CtrlCorpo` which in turn is under the
>   control Barcode.

In Angular a `Parent` controller can't modify the data of a `Child` controller. But a child controller does have access, and can modify the parent's scope variable via the use of `$scope.$parent.varName`. There is a great article on this [Here](https://rclayton.silvrback.com/parent-child-controller-communication).

You are attempting to access a scope variable inside the outer controller. Look at the example I put together which replicates the problem you are encountering.

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("OuterCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.myOuterCtrlVariable = "OuterCtrl";
});

app.controller("InnerCtrlOne", function($scope){
  $scope.ok = function(data){
     $scope.myOuterCtrlVariable = data;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="OuterCtrl">
    OUTSIDE: {{myOuterCtrlVariable}}

     <div ng-controller="InnerCtrlOne">
       INSIDE: {{myOuterCtrlVariable}}
       <button ng-click="ok('From Inner Ctrl')">OK</button>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To fix this, You can `$broadcast` an event when your `textfield` takes in the amount of data your need in order to process it. The event will propagate down the `$scope` and hit the `ChildCtrl` where the `Button` lives; then you can execute the Button with the data passed down to it from above (above being the parent controller).

Its good to note here that using `$broadcast` dispatches an event name downwards to all child scopes while using `$emit` will make it go upwards.

Read [here](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/angularjs/HM0L291214-Understanding-$emit,-$broadcast-and-$on-in-AngularJS.html) for more information on `$emit` vs `$broadcast`.

Take a look at this example on how to accomplish this with `$broadcast`.

```
function firstCtrl($scope)
{
    $scope.$broadcast('someEvent', [1,2,3]);
}

function secondCtrl($scope)
{
    $scope.$on('someEvent', function(event, mass) { console.log(mass); });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dayan, I'll Learn about this... I don't solved yet, I'm learning AngularJS... These controllers can be a bit confusing, especially when we do not have a lot of stuff about this in my native language. Soon I will test, must learn first about service.

Comment: My previous answer had incorrect information, I've updated it with what i believe will be a valid solution. Notice that your controller (the one holding the input field data) is the Parent. Parent controllers CAN NOT communicate with the child controller (Where your button lives) but the ChildController CAN communicate upwards (where you parent ctrl lives)... I've included a link to clarify this for you for future reference. I've also included a fix - You can make use of events to broadcast that a change occurred then click the button.